# Gluon ListView with custom objects crashing on scroll in android

Tags: android, listview, javafx, gluon

Created a ListView of custom objects. On scrolling the listview see that the app crashes on Android.

Note: The ListView scroll is working on the gluon desktop application:

**Controller code to create the ListView**

```
  List<Map<String, String>> li = BinfMobileApp.service.getList();

    ObservableList<Map<String, String>> messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < li.size(); i++) {
        messages.add(li.get(i));

    }
        ListView<Map<String, String>> messageList2 = new ListView<>(messages);

    messageList2.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

    messageList2.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Map<String, String> item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null || item.get("SUBJECT") == null) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {

                ListTile tile = new ListTile();
                tile.textProperty().setAll(item.get("SUBJECT"));
                tile.setPrefHeight(50);
                tile.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                        selectedMessage = messageList2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                        Parent home_page;
                        try {

                            home_page = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("messageDetail.fxml"));
                            Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(home_page);
                            Stage home_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                            home_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
                            home_stage.show();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(SecondaryPresenter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        System.out.println("clicked on " + messageList2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().get("SUBJECT"));
                    }
                });
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(tile);

            }
        }

    }
    );

    messagesVBox.getChildren().add(messageList2);
```

**Android error log:**

10-31 15:09:59.250  1042  1072 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-31 15:09:59.250  1042  1072 I GLASS   : Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-31 15:09:59.251  1042  1072 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-31 15:09:59.251  1042  1072 I GLASS   : Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-31 15:09:59.252  1042  1072 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-31 15:09:59.252  1042  1072 I GLASS   : Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-31 15:09:59.252  1042  1072 I System.out: don't add points, primary = -1
10-31 15:09:59.270   908   922 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.binfermobileapp/javafxports.android.FXActivity
10-31 15:09:59.274  1042  1042 V FXActivity: onPause
10-31 15:09:59.293   908   942 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.binfermobileapp u0

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this code? It seems on each item update you completely replace the scene of your main stage? This can't possibly be what you meant, can it?

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, switching scenes and stages in a Gluon Mobile app is not something you want to do. For that there are `View`s (also created with FXML) that can be switched easily. If you remove the event handler on tile, do you still have the issue when scrolling? Then please post the stacktrace you find, or a code snippet that we can use to reproduce the issue.